# Keyboard Phonegap / Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova

I would like to know if someone know if in a phonegap/ cordova project I can call the keyboard as follow:

[first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UukQR.jpg)

Where the input text appears already in the keyboard with the sent button.

What I am able to do is to put an input text and a button and when input is selected the keyboard appears as follow:

[second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUYeV.jpg)

Also, I would like to know if is possible to keep to keyboard actived after push the sent button.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can… You have to develop such UI/UX by yourself, but it is common anyway